# Resuming curl download that goes through some bash script

Tags: bash, curl, command-line, iterm

I am trying to download a huge file via curl. As far as I can see it there is some bash script hooked in between to deliver the correct file (in that case a virtual machine that runs IE10):

```
curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/xdissent/ievms/master/ievms.sh | IEVMS_VERSIONS=10 bash
```

Due to a wobbly internet connection the download fails constantly so I need a way to resume the download at its current position. I've tried resuming the download like so:

```
curl -s -C - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/xdissent/ievms/master/ievms.sh | IEVMS_VERSIONS=10 bash
```

However, all I get is some MD5 check failed error...am I missing something?

[image: curl not resuming download due to md5 check fail]

Comment: You are downloading a 16kb script that downloads a 4GB file. Your flags for resuming only affect the 16kb file. If you want to resume the 4GB file, you have to download and modify the script, and then run the modified version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The curl command you're running there doesn't download the VM images. It [downloads a bash script called `ievms.sh`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/xdissent/ievms/master/ievms.sh) and then pipes the script to `bash`, which executes it.

Looking at the script, it looks like the file it downloads for IE10 is here:

> http://virtualization.modern.ie/vhd/IEKitV1_Final/VirtualBox/OSX/IE10_Win8.zip

I think if you download that file (you could use your browser or curl) and put it in `~/.ievms`, and then run the command again, it should see that the file has already been downloaded and finish the installation.

If the partially-downloaded file is already there, then you could resume that download with this command:

```bash
curl -L "http://virtualization.modern.ie/vhd/IEKitV1_Final/VirtualBox/OSX/IE10_Win8.zip" \
  -C - -o ~/.ievms/IE10_Win8.zip
```

(Then run the original IEVMs curl command to finish installation.)

Comment: ahhh yes that makes total sense, thanks :) #slapsHandToForehead